# Inheritance: why does self refer to child class?

Tags: python, inheritance

Sorry I could not come up with a better title.

Please consider this example:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.attr = x

class B(A):
    x = 1

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(x=self.x)

class C(B):
    x = 2

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()


c = C()
print(c.attr) # 2
```

This code prints `2`.

This means `self` in `B.__init__` is an instance of `C`, not `B`.

I thought that the purpose of `super` was to refer to the methods/attributes of the parent class. Can somebody please explain the logic behind the output not being `1`? Thank you.

Comment: There is exactly one class instance in this code, and it's clearly an instance of `C`.  In `super().__init__(x=self.x)`, the `super()` is modifying where the `__init__` method is being looked up, but it has absolutely no effect on `self.x`.

Comment: "This means `self` in `B.__init__` is an instance of `C`, not `B`." This is like saying "Crookshanks is a cat, not a mammal".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The purpose of `super()` in `super().__init__()` is to call the `__init__()` method from the parent. It doesn't change the object itself -- it's still an instance of the subclass. So anything that the subclass overrides will be visible in the instance.

If the parent method doesn't want the overridden value of `x`, it should use `B.x` rather than `self.x`. The whole point of accessing the attribute through `self` is to take advantage of overriding in subclasses.